# Nested Flutter Futurebuilder is not updating the view

Tags: flutter

I have a Stateful widget that I am displaying inside a stateless widget. I have reused this Widget in several parts of my application, where it worked.

The widget looks a somethin like this

```
  class InnerWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  // private keys for objects in the remote dataahase
  List<int> privateKeys;

  const InnerWidgt({
    Key key,
    this.privateKeys,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InnerWidgetState createState() => _InnerWidgetState();
}

class _InnerWidgetState extends State<InnerWidget> {

  // data retrieved from the database
  Future<List<SomeClass>> data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.data = this.fetchData(widget.privateKeys);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<SomeClass>> (
      future: this.data,
      builder: (BuildContext contest, AsyncSnapshot<List<SomeClass>> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
            // return a widget (a list of names in this case)
        }
        return Text('Loading...');
      }
    );
  }

  Future<List<SomeClass>> fetchData(List<int> pKeys){
    // fetches the JSON objects from the server and returns them as instances
  }
}
```

The widget is created and given a list of keys, it makes a call to the remote API to get some objects and displays them in a list. I thought it might be nice that this widget is kind of handling itself, but maybe it's bad design?

What happens, is that the `fetchData()` method is never called and the "Loading..." is displayed forever. However `snapshot.hasData` does return true, so I'm thinking this is some kind of repainting issue.

The view I am talking about, where this is used is a detail view, which you navigate to from a list (ListView). I am using this exact same **InnerWidget** in the the elements inside the ListView, where it works perfectly fine. But when I click on the item to navigate to the detail page, the same **InnerWidget** does not work. (I know fetching the same data twice is not good, I have that in the back of my head to change it, and there's already a Cache underneath). Maybe this has something to do with the preserved state in the ElementTree? That because I am using the same **InnerWidgit**, it's preserving its state and not rerendering?

I hope I phrased my question well enough, I did not want to throw hundreds of lines of code at you, that's why created this minimal example of the widget at least. I can add the list and navigation part too if needed, but maybe this is something, that somebody that has worked more with Flutter, knows right away, I'm only 3 weeks in.

Comment: I’m not really sure but it worth trying, can you write the same code inside initState in didUpdateWidget and see if it works?

Comment: Didn't change anything unfortunately. When googleing around I also stumbled upon the didWidgetUpdate method and thought this might be a solution. But turns out it doesn't help in my case. I probably have to make the outer widget a stateful widget and call setState, however I do not have any information about the state of the data in the inner widgit, within the outer widgit. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: I tried to make an example base on your explanation and it works even without `didUpdateWidget`. I guess you should show more details. if you like I can show my code too.

Comment: I got it to work. Usually I make every single member variable @required, unless it really is optional. But I didn't for that partiucal view, that's why Flutter did not complain that I did not pass the private keys to that view. Which meant that the InnerWidget fetched the data, however it was an empty list. So it said it has data, but it still displayed "Loading...", because the list of objects was empty... . Super sorry to have wasted your time but really grateful, that you tried to help me. Thanks you :)